# Is it possible to schedule facebook post with RESTfb java api?

Tags: facebook, restfb

As in title. I would like to schedule post for my facebook page with restfb api. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post to Facebook Page wall using RestFB api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491433/post-to-facebook-page-wall-using-restfb-api)

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the `scheduled_publish_time` parameter while sending the request. The parameter is a unix timestamp and should be between 10 minutes to 6 months from the publish time.

You may change the schedule time by updating the post afterwards.